# Not able to fech dynamic created input field value in jquery php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to get value from dynamic created input field But its not fetching. its fetching only static field row.

Bellow is my code

```
<input type="text" id="job_title_id" name ="job_title_id[]" value="<?php echo set_value('job_title_id'); ?>">
```

script for creating dynamic input box

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var max_fields      = 3;                      //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");    //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");     //Add button ID
  var x = 1;                                         //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){              //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){                         //max input box allowed
        x++;                                    //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="detailroweno"><span class="code"><input type="text" name="job_title_id[]"/></span></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });
})
```

Once i submit the code i am trying to get value on controller in codeigniter by dynamic created field data is not displaying

I tried to display using bellow php code in controller once i click to submit form

print_r($_REQUEST);

$results=$this->input->post('job_title_id');

print_r($results);

even i follow this link
http://www.infotuts.com/dynamically-add-input-fields-submit-to-database/
Please help me out of this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.input_fields_wrap` wrapper is inside or outside of your form??

Comment: .input_fields_wrap is inside the form

Comment: Why you have placed `[]` in name?

Comment: To make job_title_id as array. because there will create multiple input field with job_title_id

Comment: Did you find the answer i'm looking for the same issue?

Comment: Not yet.. i will update once i will find it. Its working with core PHP. But facing problem with codeigniter view page.

Comment: Is this solved already or not?

Comment: yes.. it got resolved.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by putting input tag into form. Your input tag isn't in form tag.